# How to delete a module created from "Ultimate Module Creator"

Tags: magento-1.8, extensions

I am using the Ultimate Module Creator for creating some custom module.
When I save the module in an archive pack, it displayed in the admin grid inside it.

Now I want to delete the module I created and I didn't find the delete link. There is only a download link there.
How can I delete modules from the grid section in the admin panel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just go to your file system in `var/modulecreator/package` and delete the file named `[Namespace]_[Module].xml`. This will make it disappear from the grid.
To delete any trace of the module, if you didn't install it, just remove this file 
`var/modulecretor/[Namespace]_[Module].tgz` and `var/modulecreator/package/[Namespace]_[Module].log`

---

<sub>I'm flattered to I see a question about my extension on SO.</sub>

Comment: yeah its really good to use it, one thing more i didn't find in `Atrribute Type`  dropdown or multiselect option for declaring the field. So how cant I declare any dropdown or multiselect field

Comment: @waseem The version you are using does not support dropdowns and multiselects. But I'm working on a new version that will not be backwards compatible that supports this. https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9. It is still under development so it may have big bugs in it. If you decide to try it out, please submit any bug you find. It will help me make it better, and release it faster.